# Accessing broken Nexus 6

Tags: broken-screen, nexus-6

Since I cannot comment on existing posts yet to get the answers I need there:

My Nexus 6 screen shattered, and the USB port on the phone might be damaged.  I managed to get it to charge eventually, but my PC can't recognize my phone.

"The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it."

I have an OTG Cable, so in theory I can click things on the phone, but (even though I don't have to enter a passcode to unlock the phone) I can't access it via PC after it is unlocked.

In a clever attempt, I put a USB 4 port extension on the OTG Cable and connected a USB to HDMI cable (so I would have a display) and a nano receiver for a mouse and keyboard (so I would have control), but I'm not able to see anything on the monitor.

Even if I connect the USB to HDMI cord directly to the OTG Cable, then I'm still not seeing anything on the monitor.

I know the phone works (as my old alarms went off this morning), but I can't speak to if debugging or WIFI is working (as I moved and its different WAPs).

I did happen to get another of the same phone, and (as that screen isn't made anymore,) I could switch the screen from the new phone to the old phone, but then I'd have to switch it back.

I would appreciate it if someone could offer an alternative to get files off of that phone.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your additional question about bootloader - you are supposed to boot custom recovery from accessible bootloader on your device, decipher /data && pull out content.

You don't need to put bootloader on your device - it is already present on dedicated partition and has a function of initiating kernel bootstrap of installed operating system.

If you don't know or understand what bootloader is, what are the differences between locked and unlocked states, I suggest introductory reading after [Google search](https://www.google.de/search?ei=AvglWrP-FYvX6QSdzZXgCw&q=bootloader+android&oq=bootloader+android&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l5j0i22i30k1l4.7538.7538.0.7820.1.1.0.0.0.0.127.127.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.126....0.7_iATiSL9d8).

Basically, the outcome depends on facts is your device is encrypted (it should be, as that is Nexus 6), is bootloader already unlocked and is USB port functioning.

For this you need ADB && Fastboot, hence you should download [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) for platform you are using.

Also, if you use Windows platform, you must obtain [appropriate drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html).

Issue all commands from platform-tools directory - where ADB && Fastboot commands in Android SDK are actually located.

If bootloader is unlocked, you should first power on your device in bootloader mode. Download appropriate [recovery](https://eu.dl.twrp.me/shamu) and rename it as twrp.img. Issue command in regard to path where recovery image is located

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
```

If your device doesn't have default encryption, after recovery is booted issue command

```
adb shell twrp decrypt $PASSWORD
```

where $PASSWORD is your PIN, pattern in numerical representation or password used for encryption. If default encryption is used, it should be automatically deciphered.

When decryption is ended, make extraction directory and issue command in regard to path where extraction directory is located

```
mkdir SHAMU_extracted
```

```
adb pull /sdcard /path-to-extraction-directory
```

If decryption is unsuccessful or bootloader is locked, then, put working  display temporarily and extract data.

If you can still navigate with broken display on target device you can try to navigate with second working device to Developer options and enable USB debugging, hence pulling data out.

But, do not try to navigate with second working device to Developer options on device with broken display and select Enable OEM unlock or unlock bootloader on device with broken display - your data will be wiped.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm trying to go through this and I need some clarification: is bootloader something for my phone, that I can't use so how am I to put it on the phone?